# How can I add a active class to a svg path?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a active class so that whenever I click on a path it will be active until I click the other one. The minimal way of doing this would be appreciable. I already made this svg clickable using jquery. [image: Please see the demo img]. Here is my jquery code-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#mySVG').load("bd-map.html", function () {

    $("#bd-map").click(function (evt) {
        switch (evt.target.id) {
            case "panchagarh":
                $('#info').load('info.html #panchagarh')     //loading data from info.html
                break;
            case "bandarban":
                $('#info').load('info.html #bandarban')     //loading data from info.html
                break;
            case "comilla":
                $('#info').load('info.html #comilla')
                break;
            case "sylhet":
                $('#info').load('info.html #sylhet')
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, assuming the element you want the class added to is an SVG that lives inside the `#bd-map` container. The trick is that you're either clicking on the path or text element, so you have to sniff for `tagName` and then react accordingly. The path to the `path` from the `text` element is `$(evt.target).parent().prev('path')` (keeping things in jQuery)

```
$("#bd-map").click(function(evt) {
  $("#bd-map").find('path').removeClass('active');
  let targ = evt.target.tagName === 'path' ? $(evt.target) : $(evt.target).parent().prev('path');
  console.log(targ.attr('id'))
  targ.addClass('active')
  switch (targ.attr('id')) {
    case "panchagarh":
      $('#info').load('info.html #panchagarh') //loading data from info.html
      break;
    case "bandarban":
      $('#info').load('info.html #bandarban') //loading data from info.html
      break;
    case "comilla":
      $('#info').load('info.html #comilla')
      break;
    case "sylhet":
      $('#info').load('info.html #sylhet')
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: yes you're right, but its not working, can your please see the code again

Comment: @TomarTunes - can you post a sample of the code, so I can see how elements are put together inside of the `#bd-map`  container? - pls add it (formatted) into your question. THanks

Comment: yes you can see here - https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Me1KAvZHDwM26Z4aNnL

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. What I am not sure of is what the evt.target is - is it the `<path`?

Comment: evt is the event that when a user click the evt will return the id of this path.

Comment: @Kinglish- appreciate your hard work sir. but your updated one also not working. here is the updated one- https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ewPeeJ5MG9

Comment: Ok., try this latest revision. The issue, I think, is that depending on what you click on (path or text inside the path), your evt.target will be different. This latest code checks for the target being a path, and if not it finds it. I tried to make a snippet but the map code is too long for it

Comment: That latest jfiddle doesn't show anything and I don't want to go through the uncommented repo. Did my last comment help?

Comment: @Kinglish- I am sorry No your latest revision also not working. you can see the latest fiddle- https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Me1UYK7eBCeu94HKb9F

Comment: I updated my answer based on https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Me1UYK7eBCeu94HKb9F - please take a look